How can I find all the Strongs Concordance words that originate from a certain root word?
I use the Interlinear tools of the Blue Letter Bible website to find the original Hebrew or Greek words used in verses, as compiled by the Strongs Concordance.
If the word is a not a primitive root (Hebrew) or a primary verb (Greek), then there will be a hyperlink to which primitive root or primary verb it originates from.
My question is, is there a way of finding all the words in the Strongs concordance that are related to a certain primitive root or primary verb?
My method at the moment is to check the next Strongs entries before, or after, the root word. However, I know that sometimes there will be words that are not numerically adjacent, and therefore I have no way of finding them unless I come upon them by chance.

Look here - https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/1-1.htm

The BDB lexicon orders words by their root: https://www.sefaria.org/BDB?tab=contents

See my comment below @Dottard, in case you should have any insight?

Thanks to @Dottard's advice a couple of years ago, I switched from Blue Letter Bible to Biblehub's tools. For what you request, they have a link that includes a list of various uses of root words according to Strong's. For example, I typed the word "god" in their search engine was was led to this page. At the bottom of the page is a list in both Hebrew and English that I think matches your request.


Brilliant! Looking now, it seems to be just what I need. Thank you Dan Fefferman and thank you @Dottard.

Actually, I'm sorry to say this is not what I was looking for, after all.
You see, if I enter Genesis 15:6 and select the Hebrew for "and he believed", it leads to the Strongs entry Hebrew 539. As you've shown, it will then show me all the occurrences of Hebrew 539. Bible Hub does go a step further than Blue Letter Bible and show the specific forms of the root, and their occurrences, which is useful and something I'm glad to discover!

However, through a more laboured method I've found that Strongs Hebrew 530 and 529 derive from 539. I only wish there was a way of looking this up more easily?

I'll link @Dottard too. Not sure if this is how I do it.

IF you download a program called ESword, I think this is what you are looking for. It shows the strongs concordance number under every word as you read the passages. You click on the word or the number and it gives you the original word and shows where the word derived from. You can then click on that to see the root. Hope this helps.
